# Reading a Hive EXPLAIN query plan?

Tags: hive, hiveql

Are there any good guides to reading the query plan that comes from EXPLAIN on Hive?  I can guess at a lot of the stuff, but there are some cryptic things in there.

Comment: check if this is useful https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Explain